# How to reuse event

Tags: c#

I am creating one c# project. In this project I have one mdi form and many child forms. 
All the child forms contains one panel named as panel1. 
Now when child form opens i use the following code in all child form
all child forms' load event contains the following line.

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

and all child forms' resize event contains the following line.

```
panel1.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - panel1.Width) / 2;
panel1.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height - panel1.Height) / 2;
```

so my question is if possible that the above code i write only once so i donot write this code in all the child forms load and resize event.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You have to `pull up` common functionality into base class event handlers, and then invoke them from child ones:

```
public partial class BaseForm : Form
{
    public BaseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.FormLoad);
        this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.FormResize);
    }

    protected virtual void FormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }

    protected virtual void FormResize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - panel1.Width) / 2;
        panel1.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height - panel1.Height) / 2;
    }
    ...
}

public class DerivedForm : BaseForm
{
    protected override void FormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.FormLoad(sender, e);
        // specific code goes here
    }

    protected override void FormResize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.FormResize(sender, e);
        // specific code goes here
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. form maximized code properly works. but in BaseForm class file constructor `InitializeComponent();` statement has red underline error and in the word `pane1` also has a red underline error.

Comment: @user3216114: That is because you don't need it. Just remove it.

Comment: Yes, maximized event fires but panel resizing not fired.

Comment: @user3216114, if you want to handle panel's `Resize` event, then you should attach handler to it, and not to `Form.Resize`. Simply change this line `this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.FormResize);` to `this.panel1.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.FormResize);`

Comment: Yuriy Thanks you so much. But in class file panel1 is not appeared. when i write this. then panel1 property is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a base class and derive every child class from it.

Like this:

```
public class FormBase : Form
{
    public FormBase()
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

        // put more generic code here
    }

    ... // or here
}

public class YourMdiChild : FormBase
{
    ... // all code specific for that child
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But in which place i create base class i mean take any extra class file

Comment: Indeed just create a new class file. Change `: Form` in every child form to `: FormBase` and you will be okay.

Comment: @user3216114: Any luck?

Comment: Yes, maximized event fires but panel resizing not fired.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to do it before opening the child form!

```
public class ChildForm : Form
{
    public void doTheSizing()
    {
        // make it maximize...
        // your sizing of pannel...
        // etc...
    }
}
public partial class ParentForm : Form
{
    public ParentForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChildForm childForm01 = new ChildForm();
        childForm01.doTheSizing();

        // now show the child window using Show() or ShowDialog().
        childForm01.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```